# Является ли ошибкой переопределение конструктора без parent::__construct() внутри?

Tags: php, наследование, конструктор

Правильно ли полностью переопределять конструктор родителя в PHP без parent::__construct()?

Заметил, что PHPStorm ругается на «missing parent constructor call».

Comment: В зависимости от того какую цель при переопределении конструктора вы преследуете. Если вы хотите лишь дополнить логику, то сначала вызываете родительский конструктор, а позже пишете свой код. Если вы хотите в корни изменить конструктор - не вызывайте.

Comment: Это не ошибка, это просто "предупреждение" (или как оно там называется). Он намекает "а не забыли ли Вы упомянуть родительский конструктор?". Как написал товарищ выше "не надо - не вызывайте".

Answer (score 4):

С точки зрения ООП конструктор нужен для того, чтобы привести объект в корректное (допустимое) состояние до того, как мы начнём работать с ним.

Если конструктор был вызван и при этом не вывалилось никаких ошибок, то это говорит нам: «Всё ОК, объект инициализирован, он в корректном состоянии, и с ним можно работать».

При наследовании имеет место схожая логика вещей. Если мы расширяем класс, то должны убедиться, что его конструктор был вызван для корректной инициализации объекта. Мы можем **дополнять** эту логику инициализации в конструкторе нового класса, но не имеем права **убирать или полностью перекрывать её**, потому что в таком случае нарушается инкапсуляция базового класса.

Именно поэтому, с точки зрения ООП **переопределение конструктора без вызова в нём `parent::__construct()` является ошибкой**.

И именно поэтому некоторые языки программирования не позволяют НЕ вызывать конструктор базового класса при наследовании. Например, в `C++` вызов конструкторов в иерархии наследования строго предопределён, и программист не может на своё усмотрение выкинуть вызов конструктора базового класса при инстанцировании объекта.

В `PHP` выбор оставили за программистом для гибкости. Вы сами можете решать, как и когда вызывать конструктор базового класса. Так:

```
// логика дочернего конструктора
parent::__construct();
```

Так:

```
parent::__construct();
// логика дочернего конструктора
```

Или даже так:

```
if (...) {
    parent::__construct($a);
} else {
    parent::__construct($b, $c);
}
```

Но если Вы совсем не вызываете базовый конструктор при его переопределении, то это ошибка (с точки зрения ООП). Это нарушает инкапсуляцию базового класса, и подрывает доверие к корректности инстанцируемого объекта.